# Sound does not stop playing in Android

Tags: android, audio, video

My app displays video and images interchangeably. When images are displayed music is played in the background and when video is played the music should stop playing. The problem is the music sometimes does not stop playing even though I am calling stop() function of the media player. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance. The code is as follows -

```
public class Standee implements Runnable, OnCompletionListener {
    private Vector<File> files;
    private Vector<String> timings;
    private Handler h;
    private VideoView video;
    private ImageView image;
    private Context ctx;
    private int i;
    private MediaPlayer player;

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public Standee(Context ctx, VideoView video, ImageView image) {
        this.video = video;
        this.image = image;
        this.ctx = ctx;

        i = 0;
        h = new Handler();
        files = new Vector<File>();
        timings = new Vector<String>();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.background);
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(ConfigLoader.BETA_PATH + "media.tmr");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s;
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = s.split(";");
                files.add(new File(ConfigLoader.BETA_PATH + data[0]));
                timings.add(data[1]);
            }
            br.close();
            video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            video.setMediaController(null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        h.removeCallbacks(this);
        i++;
        if (i >= files.size())
            i = 0;
        run();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (files.elementAt(i).getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".jpg")) {

            video.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (video.isPlaying()) {
                video.stopPlayback();
            }
            image.bringToFront();
            player = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.background);
            try {
                player.setLooping(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            player.start();
            showPhoto();

        } else if (files.elementAt(i).getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp4")) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();

            }

            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            video.bringToFront();
            playVideo();

        }

        h.postDelayed(this, Integer.parseInt(timings.elementAt(i)));
        i++;
        if (i >= files.size())
            i = 0;

    }

    public void start() {
        h.post(this);
    }

    public void playVideo() {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(files.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.requestFocus();
        video.start();
    }

    public void showPhoto() {
        image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files.elementAt(i)
                .getAbsolutePath()));
    }

    // private void fadeout(Object obj){
    // ValueAnimator videoAnim=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(obj, "alpha", 1, 0);
    // videoAnim.setDuration(3000);
    // videoAnim.start();
    // }
    //
    // private void fadein(Object obj){
    // ValueAnimator imageAnim=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(obj, "alpha", 0, 1);
    // imageAnim.setDuration(3000);
    // imageAnim.start();
    // }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging to check whether the `player.stop()` line is actually called? Maybe the problem is with the `isPlaying()` call?

Comment: It is going through and executing the if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();

            } call